# C++ Code Error and I need help solving it

Tags: c++

so I need some help understanding how to fix this error in the terminal:

```
String.cpp: In constructor ‘String::String()’:
String.cpp:16:1: error: uninitialized const member in ‘const int’ [-fpermissive]
 String::String()
 ^
In file included from String.cpp:12:0:
String.h:16:13: note: ‘const int String::max_length’ should be initialized
   const int max_length;
             ^
String.cpp: In constructor ‘String::String(char*)’:
String.cpp:21:1: error: uninitialized const member in ‘const int’ [-fpermissive]
 String::String(char str[])
 ^
In file included from String.cpp:12:0:
String.h:16:13: note: ‘const int String::max_length’ should be initialized
   const int max_length;
```

This is the String.cpp class in which I have to implement my own string class using only primitive data types from a header class called String.h.

```
String.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "String.h"

using namespace std;

String::String()
{
    _length = 0;
}

String::String(char str[])
{
    int i = 0;
    _length = 0;
        while(str[i] != '\0')
        {
            data[i] = str[i];
            i++;
            _length++;
        }
    data[i] = '\0';
}

void String::print()
{
    if(_length == 0)
        cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            cout<<data[i];
            cout<<endl;
}

int String::length()
{
    return _length;
}

void String::clear()
{
    _length = 0;
}

bool String::empty()
{
    if(_length == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

char String::at(int index)
{
    return data[index];
}

int String::find(char substr[], int startIndex)
{
    int subLen = 0;
    while(substr[subLen] != '\0')
        subLen++;
        for(int i = 0; i < _length - subLen; i++)
        {
            bool match = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < subLen; j++)
                if(data[i+j] != substr[j])
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
                if(match)
                    return i;
        }
    return -1;   
}

bool String::equal(String &two)
{
    if(_length != two.length())
        return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            if(data[i] != two.at(i))
            return false;
        return true;   
}

bool String::add(String &two)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < two.length(); i++)
        data[_length++] = two.at(i);
        data[_length] = '\0';
    return true;
}


String.h: 
using namespace std;

class String 
{
    private:

        const int max_length;
        int _length;
        char data[256];
        int getCharArraySize(char arr[]);

    public:

        String();
        String(char str[]);

        void print();
        int length();
        void clear(); 
        bool empty();
        char at(int index); 
        int find(char substr[], int startIndex);
        bool equal(String &two);
        bool add(String &two);


};
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand when the compiler tells you that you haven't provided a value for `max_length`?  There's not much to say, beyond RTFS...

Comment: @TobySpeight It's clear that the OP didn't have any effort to to resolve,  understand (or even read) the given error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const int max_length;
```

You have declared this as const so you need to initialize it.

```
 const int max_length = 128781728178278172;
```

ETA: yes the value was a bit too high XD

However this does not compile well, here is a better approach.

```
String::String() : max_length(256)
{
  _length = 0;
}

String::String(char str[]) : max_length(256)
{
```

There is another error, this declaration is missing:

bool equal(String &two);

Comment: `const int max_length = 128781728178278172;`? any [sane compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54da9c9f37283960) should warn of integer overflow. . .... *Nonetheless, for most popular systems where sizeof(int) <= 4.*

Comment: That would work but I also forgot to say that the header file needed to be like that. I can't modify it.

Comment: If you can't modify the header file, then you need to insert an explicit declaration before the constructor.

Comment: @K.Smith Older versions of c++ don't accept `const int` = so I have changed my answer.

Comment: No the bool equal(String &two) declaration is there, and thanks I forgot about adding the max_length(256) with the two constructors. It ran smoothly with the mains that I were given.